# LayoutInflater nullpointexception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add an xml layout programmatically. It is giving error at `time.setText(timeFormat);` When I remove this line I get the default text value of `TextView`. Also I have checked that `timeFormat` is not null. Why am I getting this error?

Here's my code:
In onCreate(),

```
new GetContacts().execute();
addPost(timeFormat,message);
```

`addPost()` function:

```
  public void addPost(String timef,String postmessage){
            LayoutInflater i = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = i.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
            Log.d("TIME HAS COME", timeFormat);
            time.setText(timeFormat);
            TextView message1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
            message1.setText(message);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.feedsLayout);
            ll.addView(v);
        }
```

Comment: do time and message belong to list_item?

Comment: yes, they both belong to list_item.xml

Comment: then it is v.findViewById for both of them

Comment: Right!! sorry for such silly question...